# mcrypt_crypt and decrypt does result does not match

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, rijndael

I've got these 2 methods for encryption and decryption but the input value does not match the output value of the decrypt function, can you please help me find the problem?

```
private function encryptMd($md)
{
    $md = serialize($md);
    //encryption should happen here
    $md = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->secret, $md, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $md = gzcompress($md);
    $md = base64_encode($md);
    return $md;
}

private function decryptMd($md)
{
    $md = base64_decode($md);
    $md = gzuncompress($md);
    // decryption happen here
    $md = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->secret, $md, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    $md = unserialize($md);
    return $md;
}
```

here are the results:

the first string:
orderid=1111264&cardnumber=4012001037141112&cardname=Test&cardtype=VISA&amount=100&expdate=0214

the encrypted string:
eJwBgAB//4LFthFrKDuzX7v+90h2j24xrEnKHHxefzvh5si5yKxEJxtOAo8XG923Ako0eYP7JVH03yN9LPdb/V8JghJVi8tPvloqlEOFwDHUbwBoFGHBNvTRq0vgMRN/Wlpfk8e+UYQWV4TRYYNWNWxVLiwMFWWOk6bsESDgRBkMDQcp//OOFkg5cg==

the recieved string:
eJwBgAB//4LFthFrKDuzX7v+90h2j24xrEnKHHxefzvh5si5yKxEJxtOAo8XG923Ako0eYP7JVH03yN9LPdb/V8JghJVi8tPvloqlEOFwDHUbwBoFGHBNvTRq0vgMRN/Wlpfk8e+UYQWV4TRYYNWNWxVLiwMFWWOk6bsESDgRBkMDQcp//OOFkg5cg==

the decrypted result:
FALSE

Comment: You should be able to strip out all the code relating to IVs. You are using ECB mode which does not require an IV. For future reference, if you move to CBC mode (or another mode requiring an IV), you need to use the ***same*** IV for encryption and decryption. In your current code, you are creating a random value each time.

Comment: I striped out the iv codes, but it's not still working, any other idea?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that the IV was the problem - just that it was redundant. Please update your question with your latest code.

Comment: Also, show us what you feed in to `encryptMd`, what it gives you and what you get when feeding its output to `decryptMd`

Comment: i tried commment out gzip and unserialize and base64, now the decrypt does not return false, but the decrypted string is not the same as the input.

Comment: What does it look like in hexadecimals, Amir, could you add that to your question? Ps just comment out the deserialization...

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with $this->secret which was empty when decrypting. thanks anyway.